# Understanding QFTs from their CFT fixed points

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

If I know that a certain QFT flows to a given CFT, are there aspects of the QFT that are obscured in the general case, but apparent in it's CFT limit? i.e. what properties of a QFT are most easily computed/made manifest in the CFT limit?